# How can I iterate over a multidimensional array containing array objects?

Tags: php, object, iteration

I have a multidimensional array within these arrays contains array objects.
How can I iterate over a specific array object for example in value2 > [1] > iterate all Account_ID's in members array?

```
Array( 
    [value1] => text
    [value2] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [Project_Title] => Project B Test
            [members] => Array(
                [0] => stdClass Object ( [Account_ID] => 5 )
            ) 
        ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object (
            [Project_Title] => Project A Test
            [members] => Array( 
                [0] => stdClass Object ([Account_ID] => 9 ) 
                [1] => stdClass Object ([Account_ID] => 11) 
                [2] => stdClass Object ([Account_ID] => 13) 
                [3] => stdClass Object ([Account_ID] => 14) 
                [4] => stdClass Object ([Account_ID] => 15) 
                [5] => stdClass Object ([Account_ID] => 16) 
                [6] => stdClass Object ([Account_ID] => 17) 
                [7] => stdClass Object ([Account_ID] => 18) 
                [8] => stdClass Object ([Account_ID] => 19)
            )
        ) 
    )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried any `recursive` function programming ? What code have you experimented on so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can do this by doing exactly what you are saying. Something like this will work!

```
foreach( $array['value2'][1]->members as $key => $memberObject ) {
    echo $memberObject->Account_ID ."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be one basic solution:

```
foreach ($array['value2'] as $object) {
    foreach ($object->members as $obj) { 
        echo $obj->Account_ID;
    }        
}
```